# problemas de migración Date de postgresql a oracle 11g

Tags: postgresql, oracle, date, oracle-11g

Mi duda es como generar un formato de tipo date que me pueda permitir usar la siguiente fecha: `1900-01-01 10:53:27.766` en oracle 11g hasta ahora sólo llego a este `YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss` pero para la ultima parte me da error porque son milisegundos y el FF no funciona para los tipo `DATE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes usar `TIMESTAMP`, ya que el tipo de dato `DATE` no te permite almacenar milisegundos, mientras que `TIMESTAMP` te permite fraccionar los segundos hasta con 9 dígitos de precisión.

Prueba algo como lo siguiente:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('1900-01-01 10:53:27.766', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
FROM DUAL
```

Saludos